# Convex Hull in SAGA Gis

Tags: saga, classification, convex-hull

How does one go about creating a convex hull from a set of points in SAGA GIS? I read that this is possible in QGIS, but I prefer SAGA and would like to see if it is possible.

Furthermore, if it is possible to create said convex hull, is it possible to create multiple convex hulls around points with the same value of a classification variable with one command?

I have a few hundred thousand observations with fairly accurate latitude and longitude values that also have their respective FSA from their postal code. I would like to create a polygon map of said city with each FSA as a separate polygon so I can do some aggregate analysis on neighborhoods created from manually unioning these polygons.

I know Statistics Canada provides an FSA boundary file (I used it fairly extensively when I worked for them and do have access to it for free through my University), but I'd prefer to learn how to do this on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Module Libraries > Shapes - Points > Convex Hull`

here is a screen from Saga GUI.

[image]

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe it was that simple! I was using an older version under CentOS. Installed the newest version and it works like a charm. Thanks!